# How do I import specific data from a text file into mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a file downloaded from dbpedia, with contents that look like this:

```
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Selective_Draft_Law_Cases> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageExternalLink>        <http://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/245/366/> .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/List_of_songs_recorded_by_Shakira> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageExternalLink> <http://www.shakira.com/> .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Bucharest_Symphony_Orchestra>   <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageExternalLink> <http://www.symphorchestra.ro/> .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Bucharest_Symphony_Orchestra> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageExternalLink> <http://symphorchestra.ro> .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Bucharest_Symphony_Orchestra> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageExternalLink> <http://www.youtube.com/symphorchestra> .
```

I need to extract the title from the first part of each line (i.e. `Selective_draft_Law_Cases` in the first line, List_of_songs_etc in the second etc)) and save it in a mysql table together with the URL which is the third element in the same line, i.e.for the [first line](http://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/245/366/) 
for the [second line](http://www.shakira.com/)  etc.

I also need to skip the very first line in the file which has different, irrelevant information.

What's the fastest way to get this done in PHP?

Note: The file is quite a big one (over 1 GB in size, over 6 million lines).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. while loop 2. read line. 3. split line. 4. insert line. 5. repeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure it can be optimized, but its a start. Try:

```
function insertFileToDb(){
    $myFile = "myFile.txt"; //your txt file containing the data
    $handle = fopen($myFile, 'r');

    //Read first line, but do nothing with it
    $contents = fgets($handle);

    //now read the rest of the file line by line
    while(!feof($handle)){
       $data = fgets($handle);

       //remove <> characters
       $vowels = array("<", ">");
       $data = str_replace($vowels, "", $data);

       //remove spaces to a single space for each line
       $data = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $data);

       /*
        * Get values from array, 1st URL is $dataArr[0] and 2nd URL is $dataArr[2]
        * Explode on ' ' spaces
       */
       $dataArr = explode(" ", $data);

       //Get last part of uri from 1st element in array
       $title = $this->getLastPartOfUrl($dataArr[0]);   

       //Execute your sql query with $title and $dataArr[2] which is the url
       INSERT INTO `table` ...
    } 
    fclose($handle);
} 

function getLastPartOfUrl($url){
   $keys = parse_url($url); // parse the url
   $path = explode("/", $keys['path']); // splitting the path
   $last = end($path); // get the value of the last element
   return $last;
}
```

Comment: mallix, I'm trying to test your code, but ran into a snag. The very first line in the file is "# started 2012-06-04T11:00:11Z" which throws an error. How do I get the code to ignore the first line?

Comment: You didn t mention that. There is no "#" in your post. Update it first.

Comment: I added "I also need to skip the first line."

Comment: What do you mean skip the first line? What is the text on the first line? The first line of the whole document? The first line of each next line?

Comment: You're right, I wasn't clear enough. I meant I need to skip the very first line in the file (which doesn't have url's, only the "# started etc". Edited again.

Comment: Why won t you just delete the first line by hand, save the file and start the process ?

Comment: I tried but the file is too big to open in Notepad or NotePad++ (it's over 1 GB).

Answer (score 1):

You should use regular expressions and make use of [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function of PHP and if the file is too big (which seems to be your case), you might want to use [fopen](http://php.net/manual/es/function.fopen.php) + [fgets](http://php.net/manual/es/function.fgets.php) + [fclose](http://php.net/manual/es/function.fclose.php) to avoid loading the whole file in memory and work line by line.

You could try to test the performance of [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents.php) for the reading of the file, but It seems this won't be the faster way in your case because of the big amount of memory needed.